# Apache htaccess redirecting multiple URL requests based on ip

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I will greatly appreciate it if someone in the stackoverflow community can help with this. I have a magento site and I am trying to restrict certain urls that are known to be targets of brute force attacks to be accessible only from certain admin ips.

I have two admin ip addresses that I would like to be the only IPs to access the following drive paths

```
/admin
/downloader
/rss/catalog
/rss/order
```

I tried to use the following code based off what is provided from swissuplabs.com but I get an internal server error

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/downloader [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/rss/catalog [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/rss/order [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12.12.12.12
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^13.13.13.13
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// %{HTTPS_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

My site is all https. Even using the above with with ip address causes an internal server error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(downloader|rss/(catalog|order)|admin)[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(12\.12\.12\.12|13\.13\.13\.13)$
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for that. How would I add the following urls:
`wp-login.php`
`/forum/`

Comment: Just add them in first condition as: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(downloader|rss/(catalog|order)|admin|forum|wp-login\.php)[/?\s] [NC]`